# How to Remove URL from Google Cache which is not available in Sitemap?

Tags: google, sitemap, googlebot, cache, google-cache

I have a site Hot Deal INDIA. I have added around 1200 Links in my sitemap. Around all the Links are cached by google, so there is no problem with Caching. But when I checking Google Index-> Total indexed will be 2,616 Pages. But I have added all the Categories as No Index & No follow. Still Total Indexed Pages are High than Submitted Sitemap. Is there is any way to make cache only sitemap URL's? Or There is any way to remove the URL which is not available in the sitemap?

1 months before I got good traffic from Google. Suddenly Past one months traffic decreased around 90%. I know the problem with the URL. But I don't know how to fix this. So Please verify & provide me the Solution.

Comment: The sitemap does NOT determine what Google indexes. You need to take a look at pages that are indexed that shouldn't be and go from there. Google will index content with or without the sitemap, its pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

Your traffic decline is not likely to be related to Google indexing additional pages on your site.  Google usually considers "hot deals" sites to be fairly low quality.   Their rankings often suffer.

The additional pages that Google is indexing could be problematic if they are generally low quality.  If you want only the pages in your sitemap indexed, you need to prevent Google from indexing all the others.

#### Use robots.txt

If your other pages are in different directories, you can disallow them in robots.txt.   That will prevent Google from crawling them and Google usually won't index them unless they get several external links:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /search
Disallow: /specials
Disallow: /temporary
```

#### Use robots noindex meta tag

Another way to prevent Google from indexing is to use the robots noindex meta tag.   Just put this tag in the `<head>` section of each and every page that isn't in your sitemap:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Comment: How to avoid hot deals fair low quality??

Comment: I'm not sure about that.   Deals sites often can't rely organic traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Google URL removal tool to remove pages from Google's index https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

Comment: But how can I find all the cached URL's. With this site:www.hotdealindia.in I can't get all the URL's